# Multiple HDMI Audio Devices in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, amd-radeon

**Question:** How do I determine which audio capable display gets sound when I chose "HDMI Audio Device" from Playback Devices?

**Desired End Result:** A three monitor setup with a TV being a clone of one of the monitors. Audio gets output to the TV as well as to a Sennheiser headset.

**Specifics:**
I have a Radeon 6870 video card that with 2 DVI out, 1 HDMI out and 2 Mini DisplayPort out currently hooked up like so:

- HDMI -> Sharp TV
- MiniDP -> MDP to HDMI adapter -> Asus V238 Monitor

The MDP to HDMI adapter can carry audio. A old nVidia card will be driving the other monitor over DVI.

When I plug everything in and select the HDMI Audio output in my Playback Devices and hit Test, I get audio out of my Asus monitor speaker. If I swap the cables around and hit Test again, I get no volume.

I cannot find any way to select which output on the 6870 gets the audio from the system and this is where I'm stuck. [This](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/348897-33-does-radeon-6870-support-multiple-audio-outs) is the closest I've found to someone asking a similar question.

Once I have that working as expected, my plan is to enable the Stereo Mix recording device and "Listen" to it with the Sennheiser headset to duplicate all the system sound to the second device.